# What is the subset that makes the function bijective?

Tags: functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I encountered a problem that puzzles me a lot. Could anyone help me?

Let $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the function $f(x,y) = x-y$,
where $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ is the set of positive integers.
Give a subset $S \subseteq\mathbb{N}^2$ such that
$f: S \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a bijection.

I feel that the subset should be in the form  $(x, a)$ where $x$ is still all the possible elements in $\mathbb{N}$ while $a$ becomes a fixed value like $1$ or $2$. However, $x-1$ will only lead to intergers in specific range, as $x$ can only be positive integers and the output should be all the possible integers.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, do it in pieces.  Your set, $(x,1)$ gets all the integers $≥0$.  Now add the set $(1,x)$ for $x>1$ or something like that.

Comment: @lulu Got it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a picture of $\mathbb{N}^2$ in the plane. Draw the level sets of the function $f(x,y)=x-y$, i.e. the sets of the form $f(x,y)=n$ for different values of $n$. For example, draw the set $f(x,y)=0$, the sets $f(x,y)=1$, $f(x,y)=2$, $f(x,y)=-1$, $f(x,y)=-2$, and so on. Observe how $\mathbb{N}^2$ intersects each of these level sets. Choose one element of $\mathbb{N}^2$ on each level set.